# Google Chrome PDF print viewer

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a PDF which is generate via TCPDF on the server side.
When opened in any browser it looks and acts fine, but when opened in Google Chrome - it looks fine but Googles PDF print viewer displays the PDF with about 100px top offset.
And prints it out with that offset...

When I switch the browsers plugins to force using Adobe tools for printing, it looks fine.

What could be the issue?

Tnx!

Comment: Related (but filed against a very old Chrome version): http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92218 - try updating your Chrome installation. If the problem persists, consider reporting a bug to Chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future notice, yes there is a documented bug about this in Chrome - BUT it might also help to turn of the "Fit to page" option the print popup window.